# determining the size of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, size

What is the appropriate function that shows how many are there in an array?

```
int a[10];
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 3;
```

So I want something that shows `size of a = 2`.

Comment: Use a std::vector to be able to do that, after all you are using C++.

Comment: you can do sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)

Comment: @AlexDan: You can, but it won't give the result that the OP wants.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : I see, then in this case I guess you have to use vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a dynamically resizable array:

```
std::vector<int> a;

a.push_back(1);
a.push_back(3);

std::cout << a.size(); // 2
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this with raw arrays.

Consider a container class instead, such as `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> a;
a.push_back(1);
a.push_back(3);

std::cout << a.size() << "\n";  // Displays "2"
```

Answer (score 1):

This array has 10 elements. You just happened to assign two of them but this doesn't change the size of the areay. If you want simething to keep track of the elements you set use `std::vector<int>` and `push_back()`:

```
std::vector<int> array;
array.push_back(1);
array.push_back(3);
int size = array.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

Oil Charlesworth seems to be right. The reason this is true is that when compiled a certain amount of memory is set aside (allocated) for that array no matter if it contains data or not. Therefore using a command like sizeof(a) will always yield the same result. It will return the amount of bytes allocated for your array. In this case the array is 40 bytes which makes sense because usually ints are 4 bytes long * length of the array (10) = 40.

This can differ from PC to PC though, at least, that's what I read in a tutorial a while back, the allocated size for each variable type seems to differ somewhat from PC to PC (or OS to OS).

Itś not much help, I know, but now you at least know why you can't do it with raw arrays.